# Llenas opciones del select con ajax dependiendo de un campo de texto

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select, options

soy nuevo en esto de ajax y tengo un problema que no se como resolver. Tengo un formulario que consta sólo de dos elementos para que el usuario proporcione información: un campo de texto el cual con ajax se valida que cumpla con ciertas condiciones y que sea miembro de la tabla de donde se van a extraer los valores y un select el cual se debería llenar solamente con los valores de "Periodo" en que el individuo de la cedula ha participado en el proceso. Es decir si la cedula "091525335xxx" existe entonces se activa el select y muestra los años en que ha sido parte del proceso el individuo por ejemplo, 2011,2015 y 2019; los años en que no participó no deben aparecer. La validacion del textbox ya esta realizada y funciona el tema es que no puedo hacer que con ajax me devuelva un arreglo o las opciones para ir armando el select. Tengo el siguiente codigo para el select:

```
<select name="periodo" disabled="true" id="periodo" class="select"> <option value="0">TODOS</option> </select>
```

como verán esta desactivado pero al validar el input text se activa el select y el boton de envio en la certeza de que el individuo existe. Además por defecto existe la opcion "todos" con valor 0 esto para que el usuario pueda ver todos los datos o solo un año especifico que es lo que quiero completar.

para intentar llenar las option tengo una función y una pagina php de las cuales envio la parte pertinente

```
var cedula = $('#cedula').val();
$.ajax({
    url:'opciones.php',
    method:'get',
    data: {cedula : cedula},
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(data){$("#periodo").append(data);}
    })
```

y la pagina php aparte de la conexion a la base de datos hace lo siguiente:

```
$cedula =$_GET["cedula"];
$sql1="SELECT DISTINCT a.PERIODO FROM consultas.afinidad a WHERE a.IDENTIFICACION ='$cedula' ORDER BY a.PERIODO";
 $result1=$mysqli->query($sql1);
 $options="";
  $i=1;
   while ($row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {$id=$i++;
   $options.="<option value = '"+$id+"'>"+$row['PERIODO']+"</option>"; 
    }
 echo $options;
```

la verdad mi complicacion es que no se como se reciben los datos despues de enviarlos con ajax la validacion del campo de texto se me hizo simple porque solamente comprobe si existia y devolvia un 1 o un 0, pero esta data más compleja no entiendo como se recibe si alguno me podría decir que esta erroneo o me podria explicar como recibir arreglos o cadenas formateadas en json les agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicos encontre la respuesta tenia dos errores de simple tipeo mi resulset le habia cambiado el nombre y en lugar de usar "type" estaba usando "method"... ademas me base en el código de otra pregunta de aca muchas gracias a los que vieron mi pregunta
el codigo deberia quedar así:

```
 $.ajax({   
    data: {"cedula" : cedula},
    dataType:'html',
    url:'opciones.php',
    type:'post',
    success:function(data){$("#periodo").append(data);}     
    })
```

y en php

```
     $result1=$mysqli->query($sql1);
 $options="";
  $i=1;
   while ($row=$result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {$id=$i;
   $options.="<option value=\"$id\">$row[PERIODO]</option>";
   $i=$i+1; 
   }
 echo $options;
```

agradezco al usuario @A. Cedano porque en una de sus respuestas pude deducir la respuesta final.